# Static IP from some other ISP

Tags: isp, static-ip

I'm a `You Broadband customer`, to host a website I need a `Static IP` but with my chosen plan company doesn't provide me a static IP. They wanted me to buy a static IP. I had ready to do that but they are not properly responding me since last week. So I am thinking to get only a static IP from other ISP. Hence my question is:

```
Is it possible to buy only a static IP from other Internet Service Provider and keep the Internet plan from `You broadband` as it is.
```

OR

```
Do I need to switch totally to another ISP?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can buy a VPS and then set up a VPN to forward all requests to your machine. But with a VPS it would be probably easier to just put there your website.

From another point of view, maybe you can set up a DDNS and host your website on your `dynamic` IP.

Comment: @neutinus: Thanks, As I'm a developer I won't need a VPS. So I have been looking for Static IP.

Comment: @trex Reality does not care what you are. A vps is the only way to (a) get a static IP from another provider and (b) set up your own forwarding by means of a VPN connection. Getting an IP is like having a sim card from another country - unless you have a way to access the phone number (a phone) the sim card is useless. So is the IP - as it ends up at the other provider. Besides noone giving you one without sense, there is no sense in having an IP somewhere it is is not termniating in a system.

Comment: @TomTom: Ohh, Thanks. I didn't know that. So the way I was thinking is like  getting a sim card from one company and get it's service from other.  Since I was wrong. Am I right?

Comment: Pretty much. Point is - IP addresses are like mobile phoee numbers, they are like extension numbers (to a routing block / autonomous system). The IP address MUST terminate in the routing of the provider that has it - no way to magically move them to another one.

Comment: Or you can get a VPN account with static IP from another provider (without having a whole VPS for you).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to host the website on your own computer? If so, is an address like http://trex.dyndns.org ok for you? In that case, you could just setup an account with dyndns.org. It is possible that you need to configure port-forwarding on your router.

I'd prefer to rent a webhosting solution from some hosting provider - then you do not need to care for all that security crap and IP addresses etc...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the ip routed to your isp in some manner. This will usually be by getting an ip from the allocations of ips that they already control. You can also get provider independent ranges for multihoming from an RIR ( ARIN, RIPE, APNIC, etc depending on your location ), however this will usually be a /24 of ips and I'm not sure that APNIC or RIPE have any left. This will also require a lot of setup from your isp and a business account.

Comment: Long time ago that was moved to 4096 IP addresses for independent routing AND it requires 2 uplinks AND serious fees AND a use case that makes sense in the light of not wasting IP addresses.

Comment: TomTom: please specify the region that you are talking about. The policies here in the RIPE region at least don't match your description. Here Provider Independent IPv4 addresses haven't been available since September 2012